# tbb::parallel_for running out of memory on machine with 80 cores

Tags: memory, multicore, tbb, parallel.for

I am trying to use tbb::parallel_for on a machine with 160 parallel threads (8 Intel E7-8870) and 0.5 TBytes of memory. It is a current Ubuntu system with kernel 3.2.0-35-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP. TBB is from the package libtbb2 Version 4.0+r233-1

Even with a very simple task, I tend to run out of resources, either "bad_alloc" or "thread_monitor Resource temporarily unavailable". I boiled it down to this very simple test:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include "tbb/tbb.h"
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"
using namespace tbb;

class Worker
{
  std::vector<double>& dst;
 public:
  Worker(std::vector<double>& dst)
    : dst(dst)
    {}

  void operator()(const blocked_range<size_t>& r ) const
  {
    for (size_t i=r.begin(); i!=r.end(); ++i)
      dst[i] = std::sin(i);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  unsigned int n = 10000000;
  unsigned int p = task_scheduler_init::default_num_threads();

  std::cout << "Vector length: " << n << std::endl
            << "Processes    : " << p << std::endl;

  const size_t grain_size = n/p;
  std::vector<double> src(n);

  std::cerr << "Starting loop" << std::endl;
  parallel_for(blocked_range<size_t>(0, n, grain_size), RandWorker(src));
  std::cerr << "Loop finished" << std::endl;
}
```

Typical output is

```
Vector length: 10000000
Processes    : 160
Starting loop
thread_monitor Resource temporarily unavailable
thread_monitor Resource temporarily unavailable
thread_monitor Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The errors appear randomly, and more frequent with greater n. The value of 10 million here is a point where they happen quite regularly. Nevertheless, given the machine characteristics, this should by far not exhaust the memory (I am using it alone for these tests).

The grain size was introduced after tbb created too many instances of the Worker, which made it fail for even smaller n.

Can anybody advise on how to set up tbb to handle large numbers of threads?

Comment: Do you compile the program for 64 bit and use corresponding TBB version?
Is the problem reproduced if you take the latest TBB binaries from threadingbuildingblocks.org?
Your class is named Worker, but in parallel_for you use RandWorker; is it just because you cleaned up the code before posting, and forgot to rename in one or the other place?

Comment: Alexey, the clash of class names was indeed due to cleaning up. I just recompiled after removing 'Rand', asserted it's 64 bit mode and used the latest binaries. I see thwo changes: first, the program seems to run without crashing more often. Second, the error message if it doesn't is more explicit: "thread_monitor Resource temporarily unavailable in pthread_create"

Comment: The message basically tells that TBB cannot create enough threads; the "Resource temporarily unavailable" is what `strerror()` reports for the error code returned by `pthread_create()`. I'd recommend writing a simple test that does not use TBB and does nothing at all, just creates as many threads as it can. Also try varying the stack size (via thread attributes). By default, TBB requests 4M stack for each thread; maybe a smaller value will be sufficient in your case?

Comment: With pthread_create() I can go up to more than 600 threads, where the stack size of each is the default value of 8M. I made sure each thread is busy for long enough so the first ones do not get destroyed before the last ones enter.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot reproduce the issue on our (though smaller size) machines; e.g. on a 64-core server TBB works fine when initialized to use a few hundred threads in over-subscription mode.
Maybe a silly question, but are you sure to compile the program for 64 bit, so that it's not limited by 4G for everything?

Comment: Alexey, I checked to make sure. Yes, it is 64 bit.

Comment: Sorry for asking twice about 64-bit - I forgot that I already asked. Normally you would not need to do anything just because of the machine size; it should just work. For further troubleshooting, I think the TBB forum could be a better venue.

Comment: Embarrassing, but you were on the right track. There was a ulimit on my account that was set for a different computer. 6GBytes. I have just run the same program with a vector length of 1G and 1000 threads. Thanks for your help and sorry for not finding this earlier!

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the discussion in comments in an answer:

The message "thread_monitor Resource temporarily unavailable in pthread_create" basically tells that TBB cannot create enough threads; the "Resource temporarily unavailable" is what `strerror()` reports for the error code returned by `pthread_create()`. One possible reason for this error is insufficient memory to allocate stack for a new thread. By default, TBB requests 4M of stack for a worker thread; this value can be adjusted with a parameter to `tbb::task_scheduler_init` constructor if necessary.

In this particular case, as Guido Kanschat reported, the problem was caused by `ulimit` accidentally set which limited the memory available for the process.